# Magento(1.9) Breadcrumbs not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, php, breadcrumbs

Here i like to add the breadcrumbs in all pages for my magento application, for that i start to add breadcrumbs in account page first, i get idea from the below tutorial regarding how to add the breadcrumbs, but unfortunately even i did as per the tutorial still there is no breadcrumbs.

Tutorial : http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/adding-breadcrumbs-to-customer-account-pages-in-magento/

MY local.xml file is placed in (app/design/frontend/lawyer/english/layout/federallawyer), hope you will get idea about my design folder structure.

Your idea and suggestion will help me more to solve this problem.

local.xml

**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>

    <!--
        add default crumbs to display in all the customer account pages
        this will add Home / My Account crubms.
    -->
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbname>Home</crumbname>
                <crumbinfo>
                    <label>Home</label>
                    <title>Home</title>
                    <link />/
                </crumbinfo>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <crumbname>My Account</crumbname>
                <crumbinfo>
                    <label>My Account</label>
                    <title>My Account</title>
                    <link />/customer/account/
                </crumbinfo>
            </action>
        </reference>

        <!-- Remove callouts and rarely used stuff -->
        <remove name="right.poll"/>
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
        <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>

        <!-- add the local stylesheet -->
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/custom.css</name></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/custom_responsive.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/datepicker/jquery-ui.css</stylesheet></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/fl.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/jquery.bpopup.min.js</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/tinymce/tinymce.min.js</name><params/></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>jquery/nanobar/nanobar.js</name><params/></action>
        </reference>
    </default>



</layout>
```

Comment: Without an actual error or some more info we can't reproduce the issue and can't help you. Make sure the local.xml is loaded and the XML is valid

Comment: Okay,for your further information added the local.xml code, i am not getting any error.but the breadcrumbs is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

You're using both the `default` and the page specific handles. Please remove the `default` tags from the local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default> <-- this one can go
    <customer_account translate="label">
```

[EDIT]
Also make sure you have valid XML, this means wrapping values in nodes.

```
<link>/</link>
```

and

```
<link>/customer/account/</link>
```

Comment: As per your suggestion i place the handler before to the <default> handler, but still no response.(Even I Cleared the cache)

Comment: can you update the XML in your question perhaps?

Comment: if we place the breadcrumb is inside the default handler means , the breadcrumbs will display in all the pages, that's why i am include that <customer_account> handler is inside the <default> handler, i don't know why you are telling remove the <default> handler.

Comment: If you wan't it on each page you don't need the `customer_account` handler. There is an excellent tutorial at http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/ that will explain the basics of layout xml in more detail

Comment: thanks for your link, i read and some what better understood the handler concept, and i updated the question with local.xml file. so kindly go through with the local.xml file and try to help for solve my problem

Comment: @senthil updated my answer